# Java Linked Listed with File

Tags: java, linked-list

Create a File called "Words.txt" that contains a list of words. Write a program to read the file and store each word in a linked list called allWords.

Allow a user to enter a word to determine if it is in the linked list. and if it is not add it in.
Convert all the words to lower case
Print the longest word
Print in reverse order.

i did a similar project with numbers but i have no clue how to start it with words.

```
import java. util.*;
import java. io.*;

public class Assignment2{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        File text = new File("frame.ini");
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        try{
            Scanner f= new Scanner (new File("frame.ini"));

            while (f.hasNext()){
                list.add(f.nextInt());
            }  

            int maxi= 0;
            for (int i= 0; i<list.size(); i++){
                if ( list.get(i)>maxi)
                    maxi=list.get(i);
            }
            System.out.println("Maximum Number : "+maxi);

            int mini= maxi; 
            for (int i= 0; i<list.size(); i++){
                if ( list.get(i)<mini)
                    mini=list.get(i);
            }
            System.out.println("Minimum Number : "+mini);

            int n=0;

            for (int i= 0; i<list.size(); i++){
                n=n + list.get(i);
            } 
            int Total= n; 
            System.out.println("Tally of Numbers: "+Total);

            int sum = 0;
            for (int i= 0; i<list.size(); i++){
                sum = sum + list.get(i);
            } 
            int avg = sum /list.size();
            System.out.println("Average of Numbers: "+avg);
        }     
        catch (IOException e){
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use java.lang.String instead of java.lang.Integer in your LinkedList.  Reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html may help you get started.

Comment: The `Scanner` class has `next()` and `nextLine()` that return `String`s.